# Error when building Android Kernel

Tags: android, linux, build, kernel

So I'm a NOOB to this entire thing so when I try to 'make -j4' with my kernel (no modifications, just straight Samsung Source code), I get this. 
Also I did a pastebin simply because I don't know how to use stackoverflow, I apologize. 
http://pastebin.com/gjUUws6P

Comment: `I did a pastebin simply because I don't know how to use stackoverflow` - [edit] your question, copy-and-paste build log, and, while it is selected, press `Ctrl+K`. So build log will be formatted properly. Also, when encounter error during build, better to rerun `make` without `-j` option - parallel build makes build log hardly to undestandable sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I figured it out on my own after a long time of trial and error. After digging through the files I found a script that showed me some things. I was building with the wrong toolchain and using the wrong default config. I managed to get it to compile and install.